# Find pressure of liquids without making contact with it

Tags: classical-mechanics, pressure

Is there any way to find the pressure of a liquid inside a closed container without making contact with it?

You can make any assumptions, like transparent container or anything, only rule, the sensing device shouldn't make contact with the liquid.

Comment: Can you hug your someone without touching her?

Comment: If you know the density of the fluid, then you can calculate pressure based on depth, without having to make physical contact. Does that count?

Comment: depth meaning? @DumpsterDoofus

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus If the liquid is influenced only by gravity then we may use the depth, but the liquid is already pressurized inside the container and I do not know how much is the pressure - I need to find it from the outside.

Comment: @Prashanth You should define *making contact*.

Comment: @metacompactness My question is more like, we can find the blood pressure using sphygmomanometer and a doctors ears, no contact with blood - Is there something like that to find pressure inside a container?

Comment: @elv say if you use a sensor, it shouldn't touch the liquid, that's it. It can touch the container, we can send mechanical waves and observe the change in properties of the system or anything else is fine - it is just that we cannot make any physical contact with the liquid.

Comment: @Prashanth: "If the liquid is influenced only by gravity then we may use the depth, but the liquid is already pressurized inside the container and I do not know how much is the pressure". Are you saying that there is a gas layer above the liquid layer, and the gas layer is not necessarily at room pressure? Then it's easy: measure the gas pressure using a pressure valve attached to the container, and then use $P=P_\text{gas}+\rho g h$, where $h$ is the depth of the portion of liquid you are interested in.

Comment: It is a closed container completely filled with liquid and we can imagine applying force using a piston on one side to create liquid pressure.

Comment: @metacompactness You must be referring to the old engineering joke "close enough for all practical purposes" :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft For those who don't know this joke: A mathematician and an engineer are sitting at a table drinking when a very beautiful woman walks in and sits down at the bar. The mathematician sighs. "I'd like to talk to her, but first I have to cover half the distance between where we are and where she is, then half of the distance that remains, then half of that distance, and so on. The series is infinite. There'll always be some finite distance between us."
The engineer gets up and starts walking. "Ah, well, I figure I can get close
  enough for all practical purposes."

Comment: If you're applying the pressure to the liquid by pressing it with a piston, you can compute the pressure you're causing by measuring the force you're applying to the piston shaft and dividing by the piston head's surface area. $P=F/A$

Answer (score 1):

You could measure the deformation of the container. That is, something has to be in contact with the measured medium, except if it behaves different in the electromagnetic spectrum because of a phase change induced by pressure.

There will be miniscule changes in mechanical wave propagation(for small pressure changes), but that is dependent on contact.

Is your container levitatiting in a vacuum, or how do you imagine this?

Comment: The container is in room conditions, it is pressurized and I can change the pressure inside it. Observing the deformation of the container is a good idea, but to model it, lets say a change in diameter of cylinder under pressure is tough under normal conditions.

Comment: If you can access the container from the outside you can add a strain gauge-[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strain_gauge). These are usually glued to a surface to measure how much it is strained by a process.

Are phyisical modifications on the outside of the container possible? Is the container transparent?

Comment: Strain gauge seems to be a good idea! thanks - We can use a transparent container, say some kind of plastic, no problem there.

Comment: If you can use different containers and you build the system yourself, I would suggest you install a pressure measurement sensor at the inlet or the outlet and create another sealing point(with container+a little pipe where the sensor is). That way you have an external sensor. Those sensors can for example have capacitive membranes("contatcless"), and would not interfere with your medium.

Answer (score 1):

What about change in refraction index? I imagine that a properly calibrated interferometer could measure absolute refraction index, and taking into account the temperature, you could estimate the pressure. Depending on the liquid, you could also observe dielectric constant (at some frequency, for instance).

Comment: Dielectric constant seems innovative. Let me experiment with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can ping the container with, for instance, a shock wave or a high energy laser pulse (for opaque material). Then use an optical or acoustic sensor to measure the vibrational frequencies of the container as it "rings". The frequency will depend on the tension on the container walls due to the internal pressure.

Comment: That is interesting! do you have any idea about the science behind this technique?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure I understand. If you set off an explosive, or use a spark gap, you get a shock wave in air. Or, if you use a high power pulsed laser, when it hits a surface it vaporizes a bit of the surface, and blowing off the plasma/debris imparts a mechanical shock to the surface. Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

> You can make any assumptions.

My container is leaked near top. A very small hole. This method works best for incompressible and non viscous liquids.

[image]

Let the pressure be $P_0$ at top and $P_A$ outside.

$$P_0+\rho g h=P_A+\dfrac1 2 \rho v^2$$

$$H-h=\frac 1 2 gt^2$$

$$R=vt$$

Solve for $v$ from last $2$ and put in first equation to get $P_0$

Comment: You can make any assumptions, but not change the already assumed scenario, like the closed container and a non-invasive method. Still, this is a nice solution for a slightly different question. good one.